# How is StringWriter taking taking new value?

Tags: jaxb, resteasy

Can someone please explain to me how writer.toString would hold the customer data?  It appears as though marshal(customer,writer) somehow modified the writer.  Please see below, thanks:

```
 Customer customer = new Customer();
 customer.setId(42);
 customer.setName("Bill Burke");
 JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 ctx.createMarshaller().marshal(customer, writer);
```

[See here:]

```
 String custString = writer.toString();  // how did writer suddenly take on value?

 customer = (Customer)ctx.createUnmarshaller()
             .unmarshal(new StringReader(custString));
```

Answer (score 2):

StringWriter is a Writer-implementation that writes into a StringBuffer. When you call write(), you append to that StringBuffer. ToString() calls toString() on that StringBuffer and returns it.

Marshaller.marshal() just serializes the JAXB objects into XML, and writes them into the Writer (and thus into the StringBuffer). The StringReader in your second snippet then reads from the String created by StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the reason writer is able to write the content is because the marshaller must have called a method inside the write object which changed whatever write points to.  Therefore, after the marshal(), the writer references new data.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html   (see bottom)